# Optimizing Google Scripts calls - Timeout issues

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script that extracts data from our SQL database to display in our Google Sheets report, but I am running into an issue where the script now has timeout issues because it takes so long to run. I know there's an inefficiency with the while loop populating the new rows and column values, but how would you optimize this to run faster? I'm sure it is because I'm making Google function calls thousands of times (our database is probably thousands of rows long).

I'm a pretty amateur programmer here, I've kind of frankensteined this from other Stack Overflow responses. Judgment is expected, but any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
   function getPostedF5() {  
     var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:#################;databaseName=****;user=***;password=***************');
     //var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
     var start = new Date();
        
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
      // Read up to 25000 rows of data from the table and log them.
      stmt.setMaxRows(25000);
      var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT RTRIM(IV30400.ITEMNMBR), LEFT(IV30400.ITEMNMBR, 5), RTRIM(IV30400.DOCNUMBR), IV30400.SERLTNUM, IV30400.SERLTQTY, RTRIM(IV30400.FROMBIN), IV30200.DOCDATE as Date_Created, IV30200.DEX_ROW_TS as Date_Posted FROM IV30400 LEFT JOIN IV30200 ON IV30400.DOCNUMBR = IV30200.DOCNUMBR WHERE IV30400.DOCNUMBR LIKE \'%F%\' AND IV30400.FROMBIN LIKE \'%FOR %\' AND IV30200.DOCDATE >= \'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000\' ORDER BY IV30200.DOCDATE ASC');
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Posted F5 in GP");
      sheet.getRange('B1:I25000').clear();
      var cell = sheet.getRange('B1'); //Begin depositing data starting in specified cell
      var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      var row =0;
      
      while (results.next()) {
        var rowString = '';
        for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
          rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
          cell.offset(row, col).setValue(results.getString(col +1 ));
        }
        row++
       Logger.log(rowString)
      }

      results.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();

      var end = new Date();
      Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
      
    }
```

Comment: Instead of writing directly to the spreadsheet in the loop write to an array and then use setValues() outside of the loop to write the data all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
let a=[];
 while (results.next()) {
        let r=[];
        for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
          r.push(results.getString(col+1));
        }
        a.push(r);
      }
sheet.getRange(1,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper, this worked! The script takes about 57 seconds to execute, for about 3000 lines of data, I wonder if I will run into some scaling issues once I hit around 15-20k lines of data? I know Google Scripts will give me a timeout error if the script takes longer than 5 minutes to run.

Comment: As data increases your ultimately run into such concerns but this script runs about as fast as it can be done with Google Apps Script.  So you next stop may require performing the operation in batches.